# update query not working (php, mysql)

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to update information in my database but it is not updating and i'm not getting any error. But when I execute the query with MySQL Query Browser it works and the information is updated correctly.

```
function cancelaDetalleOrden($id_orden,$id_pos,$id_componente)
{   
conectar();
$cancelado= "Cancelado";
$terminado= "Terminado";
echo $id_orden." ".$id_pos." ".$id_componente;//to check if data is retrieved
$query ="UPDATE procesos_orden 
             SET `status` = '$cancelado' 
             WHERE (`status` != '$terminado') = '1' 
               AND `id_orden` = '$id_orden' 
               AND `id_posicion` = '$id_pos' 
               AND `id_componente` = '$id_componente';";
mysql_query($query)or die("Error ".mysql_error());
}
```

This is really weird because I have other functions where I update and they work well.

Comment: can you show what the `$query` variable contains?

Comment: Do you really need the ticks (`) around the column names in PHP?

Comment: @Dirk it is always best to use them

Comment: Try assigning the last statement to a variable; something like:
`$result = mysql_query($query) or die("Error ".mysql_error());`

Comment: @afaolek -- what would that do??

Comment: @Neal the value of the variables are numeric like id_orden = 4, $id_pos = 1 and $id_componente = 200

Comment: I second Neal's request. echo $query;

Comment: @afaolek I had it that way before but i think it is not necessary

Comment: I finally figured out what was the problem i was using `id_orden` = '$orden' instead of `id_orden` = '$id_orden'

Comment: By the way, be sure to escape those values or use [mysqli prepared statements](http://us2.php.net/mysqli) (if available). Otherwise this is potentially open to SQL injection!

Comment: Be aware that the `mysql_xx()` functions are deprecated. You should switch to the `mysqli_xx()` alternatives or the PDO library as soon as possible.

Comment: I had a similar issue, and posting to SELF seemed to fix it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20158733/php-mysql-update-not-working

Answer (score 1):

this looks like a bug

```
(`status` !=   '$terminado')= '1'
```

without the =1 i suspect is what you wanted to do.

```
(`status` !=   '$terminado')
```

If it still doesn't work and it doesn'tgive an error, then you have a logical bug.

Here's how to fix it.

Run this query and see which records you are updating.

```
"SELECT * FROM procesos_orden 
 WHERE (`status` !=   '$terminado')= '1' 
   AND `id_orden` = '$orden' 
   AND `id_posicion` = '$id_pos' 
   AND `id_componente` = '$id_componente';";
```

Comment: You don't need the parenthesis either.

Answer (score 0):

Use this but see properly where I have used single quote, double quote, and tilde. Just change your variables with mine.

I have written values like this: `'".$var."'`

```
$up = mysql_query("UPDATE signup set `fname`='".$fn."',`lname`='".$ln."',`city`='".$ct."',`uname`='".$un."',`pass`='".$ps."',`eml`='".$ema."',`strm`='".$sm."',`add`='".$ad."' where `id`='".$uid."'") or die(" ".mysql_error());
```

This works 100% in my php page.