# php/mysql Update not working

Tags: php, mysql

I am testing a password update process with php/mysql. I don't get any error on submit, but my values are not updated. Any ideas?

```
if (!empty($_POST['password']) && !empty($_POST['password2'])){
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $password = md5(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']));
    $sql = mysql_query("UPDATE users SET `Password` = '$password' WHERE UserID = '$id'");
    if ($sql){
        echo $password, $id;
    }else{
        echo mysql_error();
    }
}
```

Comment: More debugging: print out the resulting query, try it in phpmyadmin etc. Does your code reach the `echo $pw, $id` at all?

Comment: You're combining `$_GET` and `$_POST`. Is this deliberate, or should `$_GET['id']` be `$_POST['id']` instead?

Comment: Try `$query = "UPDATE users SET Password = '$password' WHERE UserID = '$id'"` and debug $query variable and check if it will work in your backend.

Comment: That's probably the answer @PatJ. You should post that as an answer. ;-)

Comment: I'm passing an id in the url to verify the user when they retrieve the link in their inbox. I am try to GET that id from the URL to compare it with what I have stored.

Answer (score 1):

Just a hunch. Try removing quotation marks around the variable, `$id`:

```
if (!empty($_POST['password']) && !empty($_POST['password2'])){
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $password = md5(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']));
    $sql = mysql_query("UPDATE users SET `Password` = '$password' WHERE UserID = {$id}");
    if ($sql){
        echo $password, $id;
    }else{
        echo mysql_error();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You've combined `$_GET` and `$_POST`. Try changing `$_GET['id']` to `$_POST['id']`.  If that doesn't work, try adding

```
var_dump( $_POST );
var_dump( $_GET );
```

to your code.  That might help you debug.

Comment: It is possible to have $_POST and $_GET though. But you are right that a little more information from the OP is helpful.

Comment: True. If nothing else, it'll eliminate `$_GET`/`$_POST` as the problem.

Comment: I'm passing an id in the url to verify the user when they retrieve the link in their inbox. I am try to GET that id from the URL to compare it with what I have stored. ../reset_password.php?id=1

Comment: Ah, OK.  Make sure, though, that you ensure that your ID is an integer (right?) by doing something like `$id = intval( $_GET['id'] );`.  See [Data Validation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Data_Validation) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

This seemed to work:

```
$id = $_REQUEST['id'];
if (!empty($_POST['password']) && !empty($_POST['password2'])){
    $password = md5(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']));
    $sql = mysql_query("UPDATE users SET Password = '".$password."' WHERE UserID = '".$id."'");
    if ($sql){
        echo "Password reset.";
        echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='1;index.php' />";
    }else{
        echo mysql_error();
    }
}else{
?>
<form role="form" action="[Leave blank]" method="post" name="resetpassword" id="resetpassword">
```

Comment: One more check you might want to do:  `$_POST['password'] == $_POST['password2']`.

Comment: Tks! Just trying to get it to work at this point, then on to error/form checking.

Answer (score 0):

`mysql_real_escape_string` returns `TRUE/FALSE`

just use it like this

```
if(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']))
{
    $password = md5($_POST['password']);
}
```

It will work now !

**Suggestion :**

Go one way. Either **GET or POST**

Answer (score -2):

Is it the right ID that you are trying to update?

Comment: add this is as a comment to the question if you're not answering the question.

Comment: It is an answer but in the form of a question

Comment: So its an answer in a form of a question. Really?

Comment: ok then Sico. No problem :)

Comment: Sorry, up way past my bedtime in the UK :)